# Design patterns: Java EE Web Methods must follow a sequence of internal methods, but how?

Tags: jakarta-ee, design-patterns

Let's say I have a Web Service that manages Books. So I have Web Methods like `createBook`,`readBook`,`editBook`, etc. For each Web Method, I'm looking for a design that requires calling some functions in a specific order, something like `checkPermissions`, then `validateInput`, then `execute` and so on. The problem is, since they are Web Methods, I don't know if any design pattern could be applied to them - I know I could quite solve it using classes and the Template Pattern, but it would look very strange having a whole class to implement just one Web Method.

I'm trying to do this in order to refactor correctly my Web Methods. Currently, each Web Method implementation must ensure - manually and not by design - that is following the sequence, also some lines of code are repeated in all Web Methods, and some methods are executing the verification process inside the method code, resulting in quite long methods with more lines doing checks than doing the real work, and looks quite ugly and messy.

Maybe my only solution is try to identify the repeated code and move it away from my Web Method code (no way to enforce a structure on them).

Is there a way to reorganize my Web Methods?

Thnak you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template pattern is a good idea.

> but it would look very strange having a whole class to implement just
>   one Web Method.

Not it would not. You have a general algorithm that you want to apply in different cases.  A web method is a technical layer.
Don't focus on it to design its implementation.

Split the logic of each method of the webservice that presents the same skeleton algorithm in distinct classes that will all be a subclass of the template base class and in the template base class, define common behavior to all webservice method.

Abstract template class :

```
public abstract class BookProcessing {
    public void action() {
        checkPermissions();
        commonProcessing(); // if required. To not repeat code
        validateInput();
        execute();        
    }

    public abstract void checkPermissions();
    public abstract void validateInput();
    public abstract void execute();

    private void  commonProcessing(){
        // define common processing if required
    }
}
```

Subclass :

```
public class CreateBookProcessing extends BookProcessing {        

    public void checkPermissions(){
         ...
    }
    public void validateInput(){
         ...
    }
    public void execute(){
         ...
    }

}
```